# Thread freezes main UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

Hello
 Im currently writing a Server monitoring application.
**Classes**

```
    public class Server
    {
            public string SERVERNAME;
            public string ENVIRONMENT;
            public string VERSION;

            public string CPU_PERCETAGE;
            public string CPU_NAME;
            public string CPU_DESCRIPTION;
            public string CPU_VOLTAGE;
    }
```

I currently have a Page wihtin my mainwindow where I Exucute and fill the data:
**Method**

```
try
 {
   {
    Thread test = new Thread(() =>
    {
     datagrid_Disks.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      new Action(() =>
      {
        datagrid_Disks.ItemsSource = Server.GetDisksInfo(textbox_Username.Text,
                                                           textbox_password.Password,
                                                           textbox_IP.Text,
                                                           textbox_Domain.Text);
      }));
     });
     test.Start();
  }
  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
  {
    Worker.ShowModernBox("Onjuiste gebruiksersnaam" + Environment.NewLine + "of wachtwoord.");
  }
  catch (ManagementException)
  {
   Worker.ShowModernBox("Server geeft geen Response." + Environment.NewLine + "Controleer Aub de instelling.");
  }
```

**Problem**

> My mainThread waits for the Thread to finish, cannot seem to figure why this happens.

All help appreciated!

Comment: Your call of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` makes `Server.GetDisksInfo` run on the *UI* thread...

Comment: I need to do it through dispatcher right? else I cannot acces my datagrid since it belongs to different Thread

Comment: You only want to assign the result of GetDisksInfo() to a UI control, you do not want to run GetDisksInfo() on the UI thread. Access of UI elements such as reading or setting UI element properties would need to go through the dispatcher. See Eugene's answer below...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(VS.100).aspx) blocks the UI thread, so any `Invoke` should be as small as possible.

Put your time-consuming code outside the invoke to solve the issue.

And as it has been pointed by @RohitVals you can't access the UI control from background thread, so you will have to use 2 invokes - one to get text values, one to set `ItemsSource` :

```
Thread test = new Thread(() =>
{
    String text, password, ipText, domainText;

    // !!!!!!This one should be simple Invoke because otherwise variables may not get their         
    // values before calls. Thanks @ScottChamberlain.!!!!!!
    datagrid_Disks.Dispatcher.Invoke(
      new Action(() =>
      {
          text = textbox_Username.Text;
          password = textbox_password.Password;
          ipText = textbox_IP.Text,
          domainText = textbox_Domain.Text
      }));


     var result = Server.GetDisksInfo(text, 
         password, 
         ipText,
         domainText);

     datagrid_Disks.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      new Action(() =>
      {
        datagrid_Disks.ItemsSource = result;
      }));
 });

 test.Start();
```

**OR (thanks to @RohitVals)**

You can get these values before running the thread to avoid the double dispatch:

```
text = textbox_Username.Text;
// ...

Thread test = ...
```

**OR**

You may want to try the MVVM pattern - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx. It may look intimidating and far too complex for no or little advantages at the beginning, but you will see its merits with time.

This particular article deals with MVVM and Dispathcer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630646.aspx

**P.S.:** If your `GetDisksInfo` method uses deferred execution (like LINQ) then you should enumerate the result before using it:

```
 var result = Server.GetDisksInfo(text, 
         password, 
         ipText,
         domainText).ToArray();
```

Comment: Good catch regarding possible deferred execution :)

Comment: @Eugene - `textbox_Username` is UI component so it won't be accessible from background thread as well.

Comment: Understood. Will fix now.

Comment: @Eugene - Instead of two invokes, I would suggest to extract the values before entering into thread and then use those fields in background thread. Also please add the details in answer that why enumerating collection before assigning ItemsSource will help.

Comment: You need to change your first `BeginInvoke` to `Invoke` or else `GetDisksInfo` will likely still have the old values when it runs.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Understood.

Comment: How should I catch the Exceptions in this case?

Comment: You mean how to get and forward exceptions from background thread to UI?